# Internal resource view resolver not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I have created my "fancy-login.jsp" in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/fancy-login.jsp but my jsp page is not shown when I access localhost:8080/book/login its shown just the page name fancy-login means the string is printed as it is rather than my jsp page.
Please help me resolve it.

> `Bean`

```
 @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

> `Controller file`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoggedIn() {
        
        return "fancy-login";
    }
}
```

> `pom.xml file`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>book</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>book</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> `folder structure`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Wv0.png

Comment: Make `@RestController` to `@Controller` and then try.

Comment: I have solved my problem thanks but the main solution is down below in comments section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `@RestController` with `@Controller` as a rest controller will not resolve a view , it will only return the data.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoggedIn() {
        
        return "fancy-login";
    }
}
```

Since you are using jsp with springboot make sure that you are using a `war` packaging instead of the default `jar` . Jsp does not work well with the jar as packaging.

You could also configure the jsp view resolver by just providing the values in `application.properties` like :

```
#ViwResolver
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

In your case if you are using maven then find `pom.xml` in your ide and then add the following under version tag :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Also if you are using embedded tomcat add the following under dependency secton of your pom :

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

And also add JSP Servlet and JSTL support if used in your JSP page then only

Comment: I replaced it and then it displayed error but why to replace as I have to apply rest services
What packaging are you talking of I am not aware of it can you please brief how to check it in eclipse ide.

Comment: Okay, if you have rest endpoints either have another controller class as the rest controller with the rest methods or just use the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the methods that you need to return just the data.

Comment: I have done @Controller then its showing error 404 not found
I used view resolver in properties file but then also not worked I added this dependency then also no difference but Controller is not working its showing 404 error

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jul 23 12:15:55 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: @PrateekKumar Make sure that the folder path you  provided for the jsp is correct, also ensure that the packaging is `war` , please share your pom.xml and directory structure if you are still having issues.

Comment: I have edited my question added pom.xml and structure please have a look

Comment: @PrateekKumar In the pom.xml you  haven't provided the jasper dependency please add it. Also ensure that you either provide the prefix suffix through application.properties or via bean creation and that the prefix is right.

Comment: I have added jasper dependency and provided prefix and suffix using bean creation then also same error is displayed

Comment: I have added JSP Servlet and JSTL support in pom.xml then it worked fine